# Suppress all subreports when exporting to CSV in Jasperserver

Tags: csv, jasper-reports, export, jasperserver

For CSV exports I ONLY want the data to show and NOTHING else

I have set these parameters in the jasperreports.properties file

```
net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.1=pageHeader
net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.2=columnHeader
net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.3=columnFooter
net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.4=pageFooter
net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.5=summary
```

But some of the header and footer is still showing.

In the Image below the Green Box is what I want to show when exporting to CSV and NOTHING more, but the Red boxes (Subreports) still show.

The other info in the Page and Column header (Not in red or green boxes) are excluded like I want

[image: MyReport]

So to sum it all up how do I get ONLY the detail line to show by hiding specific sub-reports when exporting to CSV ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use code like this in your .jrxml file

```
<!-- Hides the Header Subreport when exporting to CSV -->
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.1" value="pageHeader"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.report.1" value="HeaderPortrait"/>
<!-- Hides all fields in pageHeader except subreports when exporting to CSV -->
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.2" value="pageHeader"/>
<!-- Hides the Footer Subreport when exporting to CSV -->
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.3" value="pageFooter"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.report.3" value="FooterPortrait"/>
<!-- Hides the saerbi017sub001 Subreport when exporting to CSV -->
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.4" value="pageHeader"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.4" value="noData"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.report.4" value="saerbi017sub001"/>
<!-- Stops fields in columnHeader to display more than once when exporting to CSV  -->
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.5" value="columnHeader"/>
<!-- Hides the Summary Subreport when exporting to CSV -->
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.6" value="summary"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.report.6" value="Summary"/>
```